# Detect line number of a test in a mocha/jasmine test file in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jasmine, mocha.js, vscode-extensions, karma-mocha

I'm trying to build an extension for vscode and wanted to know the exact file and line number of a mocha/jasmine unit test, given its name (it block name) and container's name (describe block name).

For instance,

If a file, test.js contains,

```
1 describe('App test', () => {
2   it('add: adds two numbers', () => {
3     const sum = add(1, 2)
4     assert.equal(sum, 3)
5   })
```

Then, given a test name *add: adds two numbers* and a describe block name *App test*, I need to get back *test.js:2*

I need this data to scroll to the particular test in a file if a test result (containing the test name) is clicked.

The only way I can think of doing this is to first obtain a list of test files by a glob pattern and then use a regex on its content.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [Babylon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babylon) to parse the test files to get a list of tests in each file. The vscode extension *Mocha sidebar* does this in *parser.js*. See source [here](https://github.com/maty21/mocha-sidebar/blob/master/parser.js).